# Cluster Shared Volume 'no access' for a minute

Tags: failovercluster, cluster-shared-volumes

We have a Failover Cluster with two nodes and a NetApp E Series Storage. The connection is iSCSI.
All Windows updates are installed to the hosts, the storage controllers firmwares are up to date.

Scenario: I'm restarting HOST2. When I restart that, the VM's are live migrating and to HOST1, so it's ok. After restart the HOST2 is joining to the nodes and I can see that one Volume changes the ownership to HOST2.
[After joining](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKEof.png)

Now that's the point when for about a few sec somehow Volume2 gets 'No Access':

> Cluster Shared Volume 'Volume2' ('NetApp1') is no longer accessible
>   from this cluster node because of error '(1460)'. Please troubleshoot
>   this node's connectivity to the storage device and network
>   connectivity.

All VM's are going into failed state... For about a minute Volume2 is 'Online' again, and the VM's are force restarting.

Comment: You might want to provide more detail on the connection SAN method and Windows OS details. For Windows Server 2008R2 nodes this article might give a hint: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2008795

Comment: It's an iSCSI connection.

Comment: Please add this information on the question body.